# How to recover from Backup Pending SQLSTATE=57019 in DB2?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I updated the DB2 parameters in `LOGARCHMETH1` to OFF.  It worked fine after bouncing the database.

When I tried to turn on again the `LOGARCHMETH1` and specify a DISK for the log archive of the database, used the command:

```
update db cfg for "DES" using LOGARCHMETH1 DISK:G:\db2\DES\log_archive\
```

It prompts that the parameters submitted for immediate modification were not changed dynamically. Database must be shutdown and reactivated before the config parameter changes become effective. So I restart/bounce the database with:

```
db2stop
db2start
```

Tried to check the database config again if the changes was made, but now
I cannot anymore connect to the database and I was being prompt with error:

> SQL1116N A connection to or activation of database "DES" cannot be
>   made because of BACKUP PENDING. SQLSTATE=57019
>
> SQL1116N A connection to or activation of database "DES" cannot be
>   made because of BACKUP PENDING.

Any suggestions on how to activate back the database? Since now I cannot turn on the application for this one.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the error code in the manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup pending means you need to take an offline backup. Since you went from circular to archive logging DB2 needs a point in time from where it can apply the logs.

Comment: how to take an offline backup in DB2? can you share some commands?

Comment: In it's simplest form: db2 backup db DES

Comment: do I need to specify a location? (e.g. "disk:\location") if no location specified where will it save by default?

Comment: There are many options to backup, you need to check the documentation. Current directory is used if no destination is goven

Comment: do I need to bounce/restart the database after doing the offline backup?

Comment: That should not be necessary.